# Import C++ DLL in C#, function parameters

Tags: c#, c++, string, pinvoke

I'm trying to import my C++ Dll in C#. It seems to work fine for functions without parameters but i'm having issues with my function which has some.

My C++ function :

```
__declspec(dllexport) bool SetValue(const std::string& strV, bool bUpload)
{ 
    return ::MyClass::SetValue(strV.c_str(), bUpload);              
}
```

It is wrapped in "extern "C" {"

The function calls another function which is :

```
bool SetValue(const char* szValue, bool bUpload)
{
}
```

My C# Function :

```
[DllImport("MyDll.dll", EntryPoint = "SetValue", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern void SetValue([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string strVal, bool bUpload);
```

When I use the debug mode and enter in SetValue(const char* sZvalue, bool  bUpload) function, the sZvalue is "0x4552494F" but when I try to expand Visual Studio 's view to see the value it says "undefined value".

Maybe somebody has an idea of what's wrong with my code ?

Thanks !

Comment: C# has no idea what a `std::string` is.  You need to export the version of the function that takes a raw character pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot hope to pass a `std::string` using `pinvoke`. A `std::string` is a C++ class that can only be used from C++ code.

Your options:

1. Write a C++/CLI wrapper.
2. Use interop friendly types such as `const char*` or `BSTR`.

You already appear to have at hand a version of the function that accepts `const char*`. You can p/invoke that easily enough.

```
[DllImport("MyDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void SetValue(
    string strVal, 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
    bool bUpload
);
```

Obviously you'd need to export the version of `SetValue` that accepted `const char*`.

Note that you should not use `SetLastError` here unless your API does actually call `SetLastError`. It would be unusual if it did. It tends to be Win32 API functions that do that.

And as @Will points out, you should use `MarshalAs` to tell the marshaller that the `bool` parameter is to be marshaled as a single byte C++ `bool` rather than the default 4 byte Windows `BOOL`.

Comment: Doesn't C++ bool also need annotation when marshalling from C# bool?

Comment: Thank you !

I've replaced my std::string with a const char * and my C# look like yours.

However when I try to read the value in the debug mode it is "V" instead of "VALUE", only the first letter.

Comment: Sounds like you are sending UTF16. What OS are you using?

Comment: Anyway, add a MarshalAs to be explicit, or set CharSet in the DllImport attribute

Comment: I'm on W7 x64. The charset is on "Auto" now.
What MarshalAs I have to use ?

Comment: I've just tried "ChartSet.Ansi" and it seems to work in this case. Is this the right way to make it work in any case ? :)

Comment: Ah, `CharSet.Ansi`. Well that explains it. I took you at your word when you said *my C# look like yours*. Note that `CharSet` is not present in my code. Without it you get the default, which on the Windows desktop platform is `Ansi`. You can remove the `CharSet` setting altogether. Or specify `CharSet.Ansi`. Either way. Doesn't hurt to be explicit.

Comment: So, are you still stuck?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you should use StringBuilder instead try this:

```
[DllImport("MyDll.dll", EntryPoint = "SetValue", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern void SetValue(StringBuilder strVal, bool bUpload);
```

Comment: Not to a `const char*` parameter.